# Equivalent of getJSON function without jQuery

Tags: javascript, getjson

What would be the equivalent of this approach without jQuery ?

```
$(function() {
    $.getJSON("datas.json", function(e) {
        var t = [];
        $.each(e, function(e, t) {
            $("div#" + e).text(t)
        })
    })
})
```

Thanks.

Comment: do you mean without jquery? because it is pure JS already.

Comment: what effort have you made?

Comment: Check this site: http://youmightnotneedjquery.com/#json for JSON AJAX request. Use simple for loop or `forEach` instead of `$.each`.

Comment: This is too broad and that code does quite a lot of different things. What specific problem are you having? Making an HTTP request? Parsing JSON? Looping over an object?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8567114/how-to-make-an-ajax-call-without-jquery

Comment: I'm sorry but `$.getJSON`is a jQuery function...

Comment: @poipoi jQuery **is** pure JS. It's just a library of js functions.

Comment: We play a little bit with the words here.

Answer (score 11):

Using plain Javascript your code would look something like this:

```
function createElements(elements) {
    // Assuming you get an array of objects.
    elements = JSON.parse(elements);

    elements.forEach(function (element) {
        var div = document.getElementById(element.id);
        div.innerHTML = element.text;
    });
}

var request = new XMLHttpRequest();

request.onload = createElements;
request.open("get", "datas.json", true);
request.send();
```

Or You can use other cool libraries like [superagent](https://github.com/visionmedia/superagent) and then your code would look like this:

```
var request = require('superagent');

function createElements(elements) {
    // Assuming you get an array of objects.
    elements = JSON.parse(elements);

    elements.forEach(function (element) {
        var div = document.getElementById(element.id);
        div.innerHTML = element.text;
    });
}

request.get('datas.json').end(function(error, elements){
    if (!error) {
        createElements(elements);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 4):

There are a few parts to the code you posted.

```
$(function(){
  ....
});
```

This is jQuery's equivalent of `window.onload = function(){..}`

```
$.getJSON("datas.json", function(e) {
   ..
});
```

This is jQuery's ajax get request, for this look at  [`XMLHttpRequest`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/Using_XMLHttpRequest)

```
$.each(e, function(e, t) {
   ..
});
```

This just does a foreach on the elements in `e`. Depending on what is returned from your ajax call, you might need a `for` loop or `for...in` loop.

```
$("div#" + e).text(t)
```

This sets the text of an element, probably replaceable with `.innerHTML`.